# Child object is not saved in DB in Spring Transaction with Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Transaction with Hibernate which has one-to one mapping (eg : an Student has mark) so an entity Student has one-to-one mapping to Marks . I have provided Cascade=ALL

When i use normal transaction using session.beginTransaction() and commit it at last both the object saved nicely.

When I use Transactional annontation having Spring Transaction , Parent object is saved in DB but not child.eg : A student will be saved without marks.

Below is DAO code :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Mark_Tx mark = new Mark_Tx(marks,year);
        Student_Tx student = new Student_Tx(name, age);
        student.setMarks(mark);
        mark.setStudent(student);
        session.persist(student);
        session.close();
```

Comment: Please let me know if i did anything wrong here .

Comment: Can you show the relevant classes/methods where you are using Transactional annotation, session creation and persisting?

Answer (score 0):

> When I use Transactional annotation having Spring Transaction,
>   Parent object is saved in DB but not child.eg: A student will be
>   saved without marks.

You either manage session and transaction yourself or allow Spring to do that for you(with `@Transactional`)

You should not open session by yourself if you're using `@Transactional`, instead, you should use `session.getCurrentSession()`, opening and closing are managed by Spring.